# PhP timeout exception while try to skip a task

Tags: php, exception, timeout

I want to execute a task within a specific time-limit , if it fails or succeed then do another one but now it's giving an Timeout exception when the time is up. Try catch is not the solution as far as i researched.

Comment: edit your question and post your code with it.it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you posted the code you are working with. I have a snippet for that but now way of knowing if it's what you need.

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);
//if it take more than 10 seconds, then it should escape the task and process the echo "I'm here".
$this->face = $this->do_detect_greedy_big_to_small($stats['ii'], $stats['ii2'], $stats['width'], $stats['height']);
echo "I'm here";